# Pytesseract output is completely different from the text in the image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, textblob, python-tesseract

The following code runs on my friend's windows laptop perfectly but on mine, it spits out complete garbage. I think it might have something to do with the libraries but I can't say for sure? Can you guys let me know if it runs for you or if you have ever had this happen before?

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter
from textblob import TextBlob

originalImage = Image.open("pictures\hp.png")
workingImage = originalImage.copy()
workingImage = originalImage.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())

enhanceSharpness = ImageEnhance.Sharpness(workingImage)
enhanceColor = ImageEnhance.Color(workingImage)

workingImage = enhanceSharpness.enhance(2)
workingImage = enhanceColor.enhance(0)
workingImage = workingImage.convert('1')

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(workingImage)
correctedText = TextBlob(text).correct()

print(correctedText)
```

This is the picture we are feeding it: [image]

Rather than printing the text in the photo as it does on my friend's computer, mine prints the following:

```
of was an am: came: mm: mmm mm bu noma of arm 523w at"
mmmhmg peaches? w 3 cm {mamma a map m: K wm} Or Mummy
didn‘c realm when Am had cm then he mmm Am: Ma mad m

Am!» adam Them was 3 W317); Ll them on arm mmm a‘met
Turn mm "mm wasn't a mm: m 313% Ham sum Am have. term mmm
M‘) It must had: {mm 3 mm ﬁftht‘ High: Or Him‘cy [asked and
hated :31 me cm of Taxed back Of I Mummy time mound! m:

come and up in: may M maxim} tin: ca: m Am mm‘m h Am raw
made m: mm mm mid and Run“ w Of iwkmg at me 5 Is
cmricbﬂ mad may or $$ka Or [)unity gave hrmsuifa hut: wake and
put 11% cm my m“ Am Am} Is he rim mere own M {high W
msihmg except & Large may of'dry‘b M. M h my m E“ that thy
```

Comment: I get the same (garbled) output as you using Python 3.7.0, pytesseract 0.2.6, libtesseract3, tesseract-ocr both 3.05.01-lp150.1.1, on Linux.

Comment: Conversely, I get the (approximately) correct output with Python 3.6.7, tesseract-ocr 4.00 (on Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: I have tesseract-ocr version 3.05.02 perhaps i need 4.0 like you Josh. Ill let you know if it fixes the issue

Comment: I also get approximately the right output. I found that this issue can sometimes be fixed by increasing the size of the image about 5 times, and then putting it into pytesseract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded tesseract-ocr version 4.0 and it works perfectly now. Thanks for all your help guys!